# How to get GA goals by a utm campaign?

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, goals, utm-parameters

Is it possible to see all completed goals on *Google Analytics* by a particular *utm campaign*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a segment of all visits from your campaign, and then refer to your normal goal reports.

You can also see goals from the conversion panel column when looking at an All campigns report (filter to the particular campaign you're interested in. This will either show all goals (but not split out), or you need to specify from the conversion drop-down menu which goal you want to see

Comment: Actually, new segment + filtering by a segment on goals page works pretty well! Thank you!